# Проблема с запросами PDO SQLITE

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Не могу найти решения в гугле, помогите разобраться пожалуйста:

На локалхосте (OpenServer) всё работает, все запросы выполняются:

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:inc/dtb/db.php');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$res = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `settings`");
$res->execute();
$row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

заливаю на хостинг reg.ru и там постоянно вылетает ошибка:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/u0349935/public_html/inc/init.php on line 18

Т.е. проблема именно в этой строке - `$res->execute();`

Подскажите в чем ошибка.

Comment: php-sqlite установлен на сервере?

Comment: @Yaroslav Molchan да, установлен, информация из phpinfo - pdo_sqlite SQLite Library 3.8.10.2, на локалхосте такая же версия. И версия Php совпадает - PHP 5.6

Comment: Перед `$res->execute();` поставьте `var_dump($pdo->errorInfo());`

Comment: Проблема не в execute, а то что объект запроса не создался. проверяйте после prepare что $res не false. И если вдруг false то печатайте ошибку. Учитывая что запрос простейший единственной причиной не работы может быть отсутствие требуемой таблицы в БД

Comment: @Visman  array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "HY000" [1]=> int(11) [2]=> string(32) "database disk image is malformed" }

Comment: @Mike, база данных та же что и на локалке у меня, те же файлы залил. На локалке то работает

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры, смотрите http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=database+disk+image+is+malformed

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры В гугле вбиваете полученный текст ошибки и видите, что файл БД поврежден и вам скорее всего надо пересоздать БД и залить в нее данные в виде SQL

Comment: @Mike самое странное, что я скачиваю файл базы данных обратно на локалку и там все работает, т.е. один и тот же файл базы данных на локалхосте работает, а на хостинге не хочет работать. Что за мистика?))

Comment: Ну например целевая система с другой битностью или порядком байт. у вас например 64 bit, а там 32 или вообще не intel платформа с другим порядком байт. при этом формат двоичного файла будет другим